# how to check no of times query executed?

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle11g, monitoring, database-administration

I am using Oracle 11gr2 Database. Is there a way to check how many times one particular query executed  and what is total run time of that execution for a current date or with in last 24 hrs? Its like history of sql run time. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Will the Query have bind variables?

Comment: I am look for a script that can be used for both type queries one with bind variables and one without.

Comment: Look at the V$sqlarea view.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sql_text, sql_fulltext, executions, elapsed_time/1000000 seconds
from gv$sql
order by executions desc;
```

This will only return queries that have not aged out of the shared pool, and only give you cumulative run times.  But if you're only interested in the most common queries, chances are they have been used recently and will not age out.

An AWR report, or one of the DBA_HIST_* tables, may also help.  If you have grid control you can very easily select a 24-hour period and generate a report that will display the top queries.

---

**Update:**

I don't think there's any way to get statistics for each individual execution.  The historical performance views work by sampling, they do not capture everything.  In practice, this is enough information for performance tuning.  If something doesn't happen often enough to get sampled it's not worth tuning.

AWR can be used to find the approximate number of executions per day:

```
--Number of Executions today.
select 
    --Executions at last snap.
    (
        select executions_total
        from dba_hist_sqlstat
        where snap_id = 
            (
                --Latest snapshot.
                select max(snap_id) keep 
                    (dense_rank last order by begin_interval_time) end_snap_id
                from dba_hist_snapshot
            )
            and sql_id = '5ms6rbzdnq16t'
    )   
    -
    --Executions at beginning of day.
    (
        select executions_total
        from dba_hist_sqlstat
        where snap_id = 
            (
                --Snapshot for beginning of the day.
                --Assumes there are hourly snapshots that start on time.
                select snap_id begin_snap_id
                from dba_hist_snapshot
                where trunc(begin_interval_time, 'hh') = trunc(sysdate)
            )
            and sql_id = '5ms6rbzdnq16t'
    ) executions_today
from dual;
```

Comment: I have SQLId for a query that I got from AWR report that generated from OEM and I actually wants to find how many times today that query executed and elapsed time for each execution?

Comment: From above Query  i got this error                                                  ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: That might be because of my assumption about hourly snapshots.  Or maybe the same SQL_ID has multiple rows with different plan hash values?  You'll need to modify the query to fit your needs.